# Not able to read in Dataverse column headers in Datasets with Databricks imported using Azure Synapse link

Tags: azure-databricks, azure-data-lake, powerapps

I have imported Dataverse tables from Dynamics 365 into Azure Data Lake using PowerApps.

The tables have been imported into an ADLS container in CSV format. I now want to read in the data with Databricks using the regular spark.read.csv(/mnt/lake). However, the data doesn't show any column headers when it is read in.

Is there something that I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add column headers when you read CSV file to dataframe. Refer below sample code to add column headers.

```
data = "/path/to/file_name.csv"
columns = ["column_name_1"," column_name_2"," column_name_3"]
df = spark.read.csv(filename)(data=data, schema=columns)
```

Refer this [article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-change-dataframe-column-names-in-pyspark/) for more information